# Spring boot load data to sql before start api

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to implement quartz scheduler for email scheduling. So everything is set up but tha main problem is dump for quartz trigers. After downloading script for postgre i mannualy run it from terminal using '\i path to scrpt'. I want that spring automatically run this script when api starts up.

I try to copy this script to resources and try to change some properties but nothing works yet

```
# Hibernate properties
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    spring.jpa.show-sql=false
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation = false

    # QuartzProperties
    spring.quartz.job-store-type = jdbc
    org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
    spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
    #spring.quartz.jdbc.schema=classpath:org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_postgres.sql
    org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = default
    spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring boot you can use @EnableScheduling inna your Application class like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args){
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); 
}
```

}

Then, you can use @Scheduled in your class jobs, for example:
    @Component
    public class MyJob {

```
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay= 1000 * 60 * 24)
    public void execute() {
       System.out.println("Your job here!");
    }
}
```

if you want a delay on start use initialDelay.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, add prop: spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always. I need to do job only once and at the fixed time, so i need to use quartz.